# Create user by identity ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am trying to send user to database using identity and sqlite, I am using swagger to contact api. When I click execute my request but I  get the following error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethods' threw an exception.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element
>
> at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowMoreThanOneMatchException()
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetSingle[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate, Boolean& found)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethods..cctor()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethods.get_FirstOrDefaultWithPredicate()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6.FindByNameAsync(String normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.FindByNameAsync(String userName)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserValidator`1.ValidateUserName(UserManager`1 manager, TUser user, ICollection`1 errors)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserValidator`1.ValidateAsync(UserManager`1 manager, TUser user)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.ValidateUserAsync(TUser user)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.CreateAsync(TUser user)
> at DateApp.Controllers.HomeController.Register() in /Users/michal/Projects/DateApp/DateApp/Controllers/HomeController.cs:line 78

I am expecting to push new user to my sqlite database.

My code - controller:

```
    [HttpPost("add")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser
                {
                    UserName = "admin",
                    Email = "aadmin@gmail.com"

                };

                //create without password
                var res = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);

                if (!res.Succeeded)
                {
                    var exceptionText = res.Errors.Aggregate("User Creation Failed - Identity Exception. Errors were: \n\r\n\r", (current, error) => current + (" - " + error + "\n\r"));
                    throw new Exception(exceptionText);
                }
            }

        return Ok();
    }
```

`DbContext`:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using DateApp.Models;

namespace DateApp.Db
{
    public class AppDBContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        private readonly DbContextOptions _options;

        public AppDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
            _options = options;
        }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're adding users with duplicate details, probably `UserName` and `EmailAddress` which should be unique.

Comment: i changed  data in IdentityUser but it is the same rezult. As i told records not added to my database

Comment: How is the ID being generated? Perhaps these are being duplicated!